# JSON $ref and accessing it

Tags: javascript, json

Assume I have the following JSON structure.

```
data = {
  questions: [
    {color:
      {name: 'What is your fav color?',
       type: 'input'
      }
    }, 
    {...more question like this...}
  ],
  layouts: [
    {row_1: 
      {format: '...', $ref: '#/questions/color', id: 1}
    },
    {...more format like this...}
  ]
}
```

Using Javascript, is it possible to "expand" the $ref from '#/questions/color' to the actual object defined in this `JSON`? Or do I have to write a custom function to traverse through the JSON?

**Clarification:**

If I were to do `data.layouts[0]["row_1"]["$ref"]` wouldn't the result be `#/questions/color`Where I want it to be the actual object that it references. ie)

```
{name: 'What is your fav color?',
 type: 'input'
}
```

Basically I need some way to do: `foo(data, '#/questions/color')` => the data that it is pointing to.

Thanks

Comment: Expand? WHat do you mean? Access it via `data.layouts[0]["row_1"]["$ref"]`

Comment: You cannot do that with JSON alone. How do you want the refs to be handled? E.g. what would be the desired outcome of your program?

Comment: you are going to want to use the eval function in javascript.  The way you have the string structured will need to be parsed first.